# What is the difference between mlocate and slocate in Linux?

Tags: linux

Having gone through the `/etc/cron.daily` directory I noticed that there is only the mlocate.cron file in comparison to what I have seen on other material where they cite slocate.cron. Is there a difference between these and their respective commands and if so what are they?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://fedorahosted.org/mlocate/ explains that mlocate merges databases at each update, which offers a performance speedup since it can skip previously examined files.

They are competing implementations, but mlocate is designed to be backwards compatible with slocate and is slowly replacing it.

Comment: Thanks. When you say that `mlocate merges databases at each update`, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @Peanuts, looking at the link provided by Stephanie, it seems that `mlocate` (which makes a database of file locations) reuses a previous database each time it runs, so any new information is *merged* with the old information, to save time and give a performance speedup.

Comment: @pavium - So would this mean that I would have multiple mlocate.cron files?

Comment: @peanuts, no, the *databases* are merged:- the new data generated when the  `mlocate.cron` runs is merged with the old data from the last time it ran. It doesn't mean we need multiple `mlocate.cron` files.

Comment: @pavium - So essentially it is appending new data to the old. Is thar correct?

Comment: Yes ... and not having to recalculate all the old data. That's where time is saved.

Comment: @pavium - Thanks. Does that mean that slocate will be deprecated in favor of mlocate?

Comment: I think so ... as Stephania said, '`mlocate` is slowly replacing `slocate`.

Comment: To be exact, what mlocate does is compare every directory's mtime in the database with the same directory on the filesystem. For any changed directory, mlocate will walk it and any new subdirectory tree behind it, otherwise it just copies the database content for that directory onto the new DB (a temporary file that gets moved over at the end). This can significantly speed up the process on large filesystems; I've personally seen mlocate updates taking only a few hours vs. many days for a brand new database.